# Short lived ExecutorService for async processing

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, java.util.concurrent

I have an method that can execute asynchronous request in fire and forget fashion.

Method is implemented as following :

```
private void publishWorkItem(final Object payload, final ZkWorkCompleteCallback callback)
{
    if (payload == null)
        throw new NullPointerException();

    final ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor(PUBLISH_WORK_THREAD_FACTORY);

    try
    {
        executor.execute(() -> {

            try
            {
                if (callback != null)
                {
                    final ZkWorkItem retval = publishWorkItem(payload);
                    callback.onCompleted(retval);
                }
            }
            catch (final InterruptedException e)
            {
                // suppressed
            }
            catch (final Exception e)
            {
                LOGGER.error("Unhandled exception", e);

                if (callback != null)
                    callback.onError(e);
            }
        });
    }
    finally
    {
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}
```

Issue is that I am creating new ExecutorService  `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor` for each async request instead of using fixed thread pool. Reason for that is that `publishWorkItem(payload)` method uses a `CountDownLatch#await()`  which in turn will block the executing thread because is waits for `Watcher` to finish. This could quickly exhaust fixed size pool.

Simplified code of `publishWorkItem(payload)`

```
  final CountDownLatch latch = new CountDownLatch(1);

        zkClient.exists(pathToWatch, new Watcher()
        {
            @Override
            public void process(final WatchedEvent event)
            {
                try
                {
                    extractAndDelete(baos, event.getPath());
                }
                catch (final Exception e)
                {
                    LOGGER.error("Unable to perform cleanup", e);
                }
                finally
                {
                    latch.countDown();
                }
            }
        }, true);

       ------ THIS IS THE PROBLEM (Blocks current thread) ------ 
       latch.await();
```

So my question is: Are there better approaches to this type of problem.

I did profile the application and I don't see any performance issues, my concern was that it was creating large number of threads.

Comment: Side note: you can replace your if null throw with a simple one-liner: `Objects.requireNonNull(theObject, "theObject must not be null")`

Comment: It's hard to advise you, because it's not clear what you are trying to accomplish here.  It might also be worthwhile to remove one or more of the somewhat redundant current tags, and add [zookeeper], as it may be that there is a common pattern for what you're trying to do with ZK that is not familiar to people who are not ZK initiates.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why don't you use a `ExecutorService.newCachedThreadPool()`?

According to the javadoc, it suits your use-case

> These pools will typically improve the performance of programs that execute many short-lived asynchronous tasks ... will reuse previously constructed     threads if available

Instead of creating a new single thread pool on each call of `publishWorkItem()`, you create a cached thread pool once and use for all your queries. The number of threads is capped by `Integer.MAX_VALUE`, so you will not be limited like with fixed thread pool, but it should be creating less threads overall.

Comment: This is what I ended up doing.